# Creating new multidimensional array from existing fours one dimensional arrays in PHP

Tags: php

I have an arrays like:

```
$array1=array(1,2,3,4),
$array2=array("test1","test2","test3","test4"),
$array3=array("2014","2015","2014","2015"),
$array4=array("201","101","203","104")
```

Now I want to create a new multidimensional array `$array4` with values like:

```
[0]=>{"1","test1","2014","201"}
[1]=>{"2","test2","2015","101"}
[2]=>{"3","test3","2014","203"}
[3]=>{"4","test4","2015","104"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you need is given as an example in the documentation page of function [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$output = array_map(NULL, $array1, $array2, $array3, $array4);
```

That's all!

Answer (score 0):

try this function:

```
$array1=array(1,2,3,4);
$array2=array("test1","test2","test3","test4");
$array3=array("2014","2015","2014","2015");
$array4=array("201","101","203","104");

print_r(convert($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4));

function convert() {
    $newArr = [];
    $arrays = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrays);$i++) {
        for ($k = 0; $k < count($arrays[$i]); $k++) {
            $newArr[$k][$i] = $arrays[$i][$k];
        }
    }
    return $newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [array_map](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-map.php) to achieve the desired result:

```
$merge = function() {
    return func_get_args();
};
$result = array_map($merge, $array1, $array2, $array3, $array4);
var_dump($result)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a job for function [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
// Combine all the input arrays into a single 2-dimensional array
// Pass the combined array to a function that will return the list
// of its columns
$output = transpose(array($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4));


function transpose(array $array)
{
    // Store the result here
    $result = array();
    // Get each column, put it into the result
    foreach (array_keys($array[0]) as $key) {
        $result[$key] = array_column($array, $key);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Another solution that works the same but uses function [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to walk the array:

```
function transpose(array $array)
{
    return array_reduce(
        array_keys($array[0]),
        function (array $carry, $key) use ($array) {
            $carry[$key] = array_column($array, $key);
            return $carry;
        },
        array()
    );
}
```